# VB .NET WinFormApplication Printing Failed Landscape mode after setting

Tags: vb.net, printing, landscape, preview

I am using VB .NET programming and I would like to print my `WinFormsApplication` in landscape mode as the portrait mode could not fit it properly.

I have set the landscape mode as true. You may refer to the code below:

```
    Private Sub PrintAll_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles PrintAll.Click
    PrintForm1.Form = Me
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.FullWindow)
    PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

And the result is shown as below in the screenshot
http://s335.photobucket.com/user/blakeex/media/notcomplete.png.html
Could anyone share some hint or guides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [to print the complete client area of a scrollable form, even if the form has been resized.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb690944%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Try `PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)`

Here's another way that will print whatever part of the form is viewable on the screen:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    CaptureScreen()
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub
Dim memoryImage As Bitmap
Private Sub CaptureScreen()
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim s As Size = Me.Size
    memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, s)
End Sub
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim pagerec As New RectangleF(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Y, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, pagerec, New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @tinstaafl and others respected members,

I have tried your method above.

It could not work as shown in my screenshot website below:
[http://s335.photobucket.com/user/blakeex/media/notcomplete-1.png.html]

Could you suggest an alternative or have I missed a step?

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer.